# How to select all the rows from a table with specific text in its header with xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm new to Xpath and I'm trying to get all the rows from a specific table on a wikipedia article that has many tables, luckily the table I want has the text "Posición" in one of the th elements inside it's header, how can I achieve this?
I am using C# to achieve this, any help and tips will be greatly appreciated :)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Something</th>
            <th>Posición</th>
            <th>Something</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info1</td>
            <td>info2</td>
            <td>info3</td>
        </tr>
        ... more trs
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show some example and expected output.  This question is too broad.

Comment: I added the basic structure of the table I'm working with, the expected output would be all the tr inside tbody

Comment: If you just need the xpath, `//table[thead/tr/th='Posición']/tbody/tr` should work.

Comment: I tried and I got a null result, maybe it's because the th containing Posición is the third th of the tr does this have something to do with the result?

Comment: lol i'm sure you're not dumb. It works if I use your XML and the xpath in this online tester: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath Maybe there's a default namespace or something. Can you share the link to the wikipedia article?

Comment: I'll try to poke around with it, here's the link: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selecci%C3%B3n_de_f%C3%BAtbol_de_M%C3%A9xico

Comment: You can also test the XPath in Chrome. Open the Developer tools, then in the "Elements" panel ctrl-f, paste in the XPath, and it will show the 21 rows that match. Remember that this is HTML, so if you are trying to XPath in C# you may need to tidy it up in order to make it well-formed xHTML